# Finding street intersections with high concentration of vehicle crashes using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, features, streets, traffic

I'm trying to find street intersections with a high concentration of traffic crashes.

First of all, I have tried with kernel density analysis, but I'm wondering if there is something that makes a sort of ranking of street intersections so that I can determine which is the most dangerous street intersections of our city.

I'm new to spatial data and I'm eager to learn new things. I´m working on ArcGIS  Pro and I have a feature class of crashes.

Comment: hello!! Bera! yes i have a feature layer with traffic crashes. There is a unique point for every crash, but these points are not in the street intersections.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Network Kernel Density Estimation and more specifically, the [SANET ArcGIS Toolbox](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.0016-7363.2005.00674.x)

I did a crash analysis project in school using the SANET toolbox that proved to be more accurate vs traditional KDE.